# image.convertTo not always working

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have a little problem and I really don't know why this error comes sometimes.

I use this picture for working: [image]

And this is the code at this part:

```
cv::Mat src = image1;
cv::Mat src2 = image1;

src.convertTo(src,-1,0.15,0);
```

In this picture are the three cases what happen with the picture, but only the first case would be right. The most case is also the first, the other things don't happen often.

[image]

I hope anyone can help me with this. :)

Comment: for convertTo, -1 is not a valid flag

Comment: @berak Sure it is. It means use the same type as the input. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto

Comment: ^^ ah, right. misread it.

Comment: the strange thing is does it sometimes work and sometimes not. The images come from a video stream. I check also that the images are not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found a solution for my problem. When someone else have this problem you can try the following.

I changed my code to this:

```
cv::Mat src;
cv::Mat src2 = image1;

image1.convertTo(src,-1,0.15,0);
```

So it works fine without problem. I have no idea why the other method is not working.